# 3 phase power convert to 3.3v raspberry pi signal

Tags: microcontroller, transformer, voltage-regulator, ac, raspberry-pi

I have a project about to mantain a data log of a 3 phase motor, when the more is on and off count that time and save in memory location.

I don't use any server now to save data, I use a Rpi to do all this stuff. Any other controller I can use suggest please.

I want that 3 phase signal on my Rpi when the switch is on, 1- 3 phase AC to 3.3v dc signal?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to power the pi from it?

Comment: use a current sensor

Comment: Not actually, I power it from battery but I want to use a charger from that voltage signal comming from 3Phase AC..

Comment: Which current sensor please mention.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbzC7B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible circuit.*

The relay separates your 3-phase from your 3.3 V Raspberry Pi circuit making it a safe system.